# How can I get RawTX transactions?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, api, raw-transaction, raw

I used to be able to get RawTX transactions on the Blockchain using the link:

https://blockchain.info/tx/60183ab915f2f4b0190605f98bd0e9f8eafe13a1c902b3ae87ecd0dfc8a599a0?format=hex

But the site switched to another domain and changed the api. If scripts for Ubuntu to get RawTX from a set of hashes?

How can I get RawTX now? Tell me the ways?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this data by running a bitcoin-core full node with `txindex=1` in the configuration file. You can then use the command `bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction (TX_HASH)` to get the raw transaction info.

For example:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 60183ab915f2f4b0190605f98bd0e9f8eafe13a1c902b3ae87ecd0dfc8a599a0
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
```

Adding a `1` to the end of that command will return a more verbose output:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 60183ab915f2f4b0190605f98bd0e9f8eafe13a1c902b3ae87ecd0dfc8a599a0 1
{
  "txid": "60183ab915f2f4b0190605f98bd0e9f8eafe13a1c902b3ae87ecd0dfc8a599a0",
  "hash": "60183ab915f2f4b0190605f98bd0e9f8eafe13a1c902b3ae87ecd0dfc8a599a0",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 456,
  "vsize": 456,
  "weight": 1824,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "1761d625ddd3f58f7f3ee213f47fcf9b3f8bbd55afab50a2106705503e5a56a1",
      "vout": 2,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100ded45306a6ac022f13a16e994c87bb3f348d13e5039a5e088fe94c79e1d1ab5e0220311339632ef240d633510516c2536ae091eb176f14548412375f6f80d45e1a6b[ALL] 047146f0e0fcb3139947cf0beb870fe251930ca10d4545793d31033e801b5219abf56c11a3cf3406ca590e4c14b0dab749d20862b3adc4709153c280c2a78be10c",
        "hex": "483045022100ded45306a6ac022f13a16e994c87bb3f348d13e5039a5e088fe94c79e1d1ab5e0220311339632ef240d633510516c2536ae091eb176f14548412375f6f80d45e1a6b0141047146f0e0fcb3139947cf0beb870fe251930ca10d4545793d31033e801b5219abf56c11a3cf3406ca590e4c14b0dab749d20862b3adc4709153c280c2a78be10c"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00268035,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 817f1daf3b1080aa9d06b6969fa162b8d75a490d OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914817f1daf3b1080aa9d06b6969fa162b8d75a490d88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "1CoiSvDYA5KLJMpriJsZumg2iZ5Ds31r33"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.07600000,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 2c4154736c01c24d66a9e9f08df10a717e8dc81e OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a9142c4154736c01c24d66a9e9f08df10a717e8dc81e87",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "35j1vBeT4iPeTM3zdzHpaz4byPcSUEp27Z"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.16038363,
      "n": 2,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 42771b8871e5df7baa107253c3ba156feb17db49 OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a91442771b8871e5df7baa107253c3ba156feb17db4987",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "37kTCwc3q8UF8wyqmSMkbzesMPbN6Bj3B1"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.16378998,
      "n": 3,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 5b90ceac145472d39366f5c174e495e754e2016a OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a9145b90ceac145472d39366f5c174e495e754e2016a88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "19M9xr1r3Un2XpUDEPxEapsHrnZNF3KdBj"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.24970000,
      "n": 4,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 2c7c79f6a4a19b8a6071144dd9ee438d1e60c3c8 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a9142c7c79f6a4a19b8a6071144dd9ee438d1e60c3c888ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "154DrDQEkazY4k27PW6khJ3LyPH7ZTjGp1"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 2.00000000,
      "n": 5,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 eade7d94aa4077025a322002a3d4f662d0bb8f1b OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a914eade7d94aa4077025a322002a3d4f662d0bb8f1b87",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "3P6taM3ogQJpzMDFkNg8coxZinbudUsNND"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 93.16400000,
      "n": 6,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 d5458947802140d1ca099ef3f5b25151183e285f OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914d5458947802140d1ca099ef3f5b25151183e285f88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "1LSgEKji3ZoGdvzBgkcJMej74iBd38fySb"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 175.09442370,
      "n": 7,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 43849383122ebb8a28268a89700c9f723663b5b8 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a91443849383122ebb8a28268a89700c9f723663b5b888ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "17A16QmavnUfCW11DAApiJxp7ARnxN5pGX"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "hex": "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",
  "blockhash": "000000000000000000203285ed3cdc4928fa74ccfc9a278c4a79caf09a0d00b1",
  "confirmations": 178585,
  "time": 1523893268,
  "blocktime": 1523893268
}
```